# Using maps within maps in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a map within a map using the following code;

```
 map<map <int,int>,int > multimap;
```

Now I want to insert the data such that `multimap[1]`--->(2,3), `multimap[4]`--->(5,6). I have been trying to insert it the following way but i guess there is a syntax error which I can't seem to figure out!

```
 multimap.insert(pair<int,pair<int,int>(2,3)>(1));
```

Any help will be appreciated. And after adding, how would I display the values by using an iterator?

Comment: Would you like to share what the syntax error is?

Comment: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
error: template argument 2 is invalid

Comment: From your description of what you want to map, wouldn't you want something more like: `map<int, pair<int, int>> multimap` since you want a single value that maps to a pair of values?

Comment: for one thing, you're keying a multimap with a map... I don't understand why you'd do that, since your key needs a `<` operator.

Comment: Your insert value is (seemingly supposed to be ) `pair<int, pair<>>`, that's not correct based on the definition of multimap.  Is the key supposed to be int or pair?

Comment: @pstrjds...I suppose yes...but then again, how do I achieve that?

Comment: @SteveTownsend...my key can have multiple values....like 1--->(2,3),1--->(4,5) etc. what i'm trying is to map a pair(s) to a key.

Comment: Did I get this right? This is not a multimap, it's just a map called multimap right? I don't know why you'd do that.

Comment: @Component10...yes it's a map. Sorry for the confusion guys!

Comment: it doesn't sound like you want a map within a map, but rather a pair within a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a multipmap then you need to use a multimap :) Here is declaration and an insert statement.

```
typedef pair<int, int> valPair;
multimap<int, valPair> mmap;

mmap.insert(make_pair(1, make_pair(2, 3)));
mmap.insert(make_pair(1, make_pair(4, 5)));

for(multimap<int, valPair>::iterator it = mmap.begin();
    it != mmap.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "Key: " << it->first << " Vals:(";
         << it->second.first << ", " << it->second.second << ")" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @AmaarBokhari updated with the iteration. Just hadn't copied it over yet.

Comment: yeah i noticed...but thanks again...new to C++'s STL library! :)

Answer (score 4):

The map template calls for two parameters `map<key, value>`. The key has to have some way of comparing itself with other keys. In `map` it uses the `<` operator, so if you key with a `map<int,int>` you're going to have problems, since there's no defined `<` for an arbitrary map.

Try

```
map<int, map<int, int> > multimap;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the variable `multimap` though... just asking for trouble.

Comment: can you please tell me how to insert using the insert function?

Comment: why don't you just use multimap[2][3] = 1?

Comment: it's working. But can we do it with an insert function? or is there a certain limitation to it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're confusing maps and multimaps, and keys and values.

If you want a map that maps the key '1' to the values '(2,3)' and '(4,5)' then do this:

```
multimap<int,pair<int,int>> myMap { {1,{2,3}}, {1,{4,5}} };
```

or in C++03:

```
multimap<int,pair<int,int> > myMap;
myMap.insert(make_pair(1,make_pair(2,3)));
myMap.insert(make_pair(1,make_pair(4,5)));
```

---

When iterating over the map each item refers to a pair where the first item of the pair is the key and the second item is the value.

```
for(auto &i : myMap) {
    std::cout << "Key: " << i->first
      << " Value: (" << i->second.first << ',' << i->second.second << ")\n";
}
```

Or in C++03

```
for(multimap<int,pair<int,int> >::const_iterator i(myMap.begin()),end(myMap.end()); i!=end; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Key: " << i->first << " Value: (" << i->second.first << ',' << i->second.second << ")\n";
}
```

This would print out:

```
Key: 1 Value: (2,3)
Key: 1 Value: (4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

-Firstly, there's no multimap in your code - there is simply a map called 'multimap'.

-Secondly, the structure

```
map< map<int, int>, int > multimap;
```

will not map 1-->2, 3, because you're using a map as a key, and an int as the value.

-Thirdly, the reason you're getting a build error is because the insert() method in your case takes

```
pair< map<int, int>, int >
```

What you probably want is this:

```
map< int, pair<int, int> > multimap;
pair<int, int> myPair( 2, 3 );
multimap.insert( pair< int, pair<int, int> >( 1, myPair ) );

map< int, pair<int, int> >::iterator iter = multimap.begin();
while( iter != multimap.end() )
{
    int key = iter->first;
    pair<int, int> aPair = iter->second;
    ++iter;
}
```

Comment: @AmaarBokhari I'm afraid I've cheated and edited the answer while you were replying - I had a clot on the keyboard! :-)  To iterate the map you want to look at the `begin()` and `end()` functions, and look at iterators; particularly retrieving one from `begin()`, incrementing it with ++, and comparing it to `end()`.

Comment: @AmaarBokhari Don't be shy about voting me up.  ;-)